# Firebase 10 random Fetch like RAND() in PHP

Tags: javascript, random, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Please i am building an App that needs to fetch 10 objects randomly from my firebase Database

I am able to do this easily in PHP MYSQL using REST but i have tried it in firebase and no head way so i need help.

i just want my $firebasArray to always hold 10 random object anytime a request is made and i have about 500 objects in the database.
But i just want to randomly get 10 each time i fetch data from the firebase database.

Please any simple code will be appreciated thanks

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923256/retrieve-a-random-15-children-from-firebase

Comment: Thanks Frank but i have already seen that a 2 others before i made this post.  i needed some specific code.